# how to save objects to a user in django 1.10

Tags: django

I created a model name song, and I made a form to upload song to the website. I was wondering how to save songs to a specific user, so I can query the database for all of the songs uploaded by a user

My models:

```
class Song(models.Model):  
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, null = True)  
    song_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)  
    audio = models.FileField()
```

My View:

```
class SongCreate(CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields=['song_name','audio']
```

summary:
  I can upload songs but i can't link them to a user
p.s I'm very new to django

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `form_valid` method of the `CreateView` to assign the user to the song and then save it.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class SongCreate(CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields=['song_name','audio']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        song = form.save(commit=False)
        song.user = self.request.user
        song.save()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```